# Is it possible to read property from project referenced by ProjectReference

Tags: msbuild

Is it possible to read any arbitrary property(or somehow to push property) from one project to another via ProjectReference? As one of build tasks I want to execute executable from project referenced by ProjectReference, but its name depends on system. Also I want to make my reference non-depended from changing output name, etc.

Is there some way to read properties of other project?

Comment: The `ProjectReference` collection is used to determine build dependencies on other projects. It is not a mechanism for general sharing across projects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it is not possible as you describe it. But you can turn the problem around.
Embedd a target inside the *referenced* project that launches the executable it builds. Then call that target from the *referecing* project.

Example (inside the referenced project, say, ReferencedProject.csproj):

```xml
<Target Name="RunExecutable">
  <Exec Command="$(TargetPath)"/>
</Target>
```

Example (inside the referecing project):

```xml
<Target Name="CallExecutable">
   <MSBuild Projects="ReferencedProject.csproj" Targets="RunExecutable"/>
</Target>
```

All the knowledge about output file names, configurations, etc. stays in the original (referenced) project.